# Connection lost: The server closed the connection (PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST)

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I'm currently working with serverless architecture using Lambda Node 16.X version, and I've encountered the following error. How can I resolve this issue?

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Connection lost: The server closed the connection.",
  "code": "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST",
  "message": "Connection lost: The server closed the connection.",
  "stack": [
    "Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.",
    "    at PromisePoolConnection.query (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:93:22)",
    "    at /var/task/index.js:1092:25",
    "    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)",
    "    at async Runtime.handler (/var/task/index.js:1802:17)"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your code or what it is you're trying to do so it's hard to answer. But it seems like you're querying MySQL and the connection has gone stale.

When you use Lambda, you'll want to be sure to establish the connection outside the request handler so it can be shared across invocations. You may also benefit from creating a pool of connections:

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: '---',
  user: '--',
  database: '---',
  password: '----'
})
```

Regardless, the connection to your database had gone stale, resulting in this error. You should retry to initialise your connection and retry your query again.